# Theorem about vectors and recursive functions

Tags: coq

I want to prove `aaa` below.

Kth element of the output of the function for arbitrary natural number k must be same as the kth value of the same vector that has undergone the same processing.

```
Require Import Coq.Vectors.Vector.
Require Import Psatz.
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect.

Definition kLess : forall (k P:nat), (P - k) < (S P).
intros. lia.
Defined.

Definition Sum {A}(v:t nat A) :nat:= Vector.fold_right Nat.add v 0.

Fixpoint Sumation {A} (k:nat)(v:t nat (S A)):t nat (S k):=
 match k in nat return t nat (S k) with
   |0 => cons _ ((nth_order v (kLess k A)) + (Sum v)) _ (nil nat)
   |S k' => cons _ ((nth_order v (kLess k A)) + (Sum v)) _ (Sumation k' v)
   end.

Lemma aaa {n}(k:nat)(v:t nat (S n)): nth_order (Sumation n v) (kLess k n) = (nth_order v (kLess k n)) + (Sum v).
Proof.
rewrite /nth_order.
induction n.
destruct k => //.
```

Please tell me  your solution.

Comment: The library of vectors given in the standard library is really not adapted to for this kind of exercise: there are not enough lemmas that have already proved about `Fin.t` or `Vector.t`.  Moreover, the fact that you use `kLess` makes that you are accessing vectors by the right end.  This forces users to a lot of arithmetic gymnastics for which you don't give any support in your question.   Please try to work with the matrix and vector types from the Mathematical Component Library instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *disentangle* your statement.  In its current form, the number `n` and the vector `v` are used in too many places for different purposes.  This makes a proof by induction very difficult.

If you look at the recursive call in `Sumation`, you see that the second explicit argument (the one locally named `v`) does not change during recursive call, while the main recursive argument `k` decreases.  So you have to have a statement where the second explicit argument does not have to have size `S n`.  It suffices that the size of `v` is larger than or equal to `S n`.

Similarly, the uses of `kLess _ _` are blocking your abilities to think and Coq's ability to rewrite.  What really matters, is that we are accessing inside `v` and inside the result of the `Sumation _ _` call using arguments that are smaller than the size, so you should generalize about this.

The proof below exploits these guidelines.

```
Require Import Coq.Vectors.Vector.
Require Import Psatz.
Require Import ssreflect.
Require Import Arith.

Definition kLess : forall (k P:nat), (P - k) < (S P).
intros. lia.
Defined.

Definition Sum {A}(v:t nat A) :nat:= Vector.fold_right Nat.add v 0.

Fixpoint Sumation {A} (k:nat)(v:t nat (S A)):t nat (S k):=
 match k in nat return t nat (S k) with
   |0 => cons _ ((nth_order v (kLess k A)) + (Sum v)) _ (nil nat)
   |S k' => cons _ ((nth_order v (kLess k A)) + (Sum v)) _ (Sumation k' v)
   end.

Definition v := cons nat 0 1 (cons nat 1 0 (nil nat)).

Compute Sumation 0 v.
Compute nth_order (Sumation 0 v) (kLess 0 _).
Compute nth_order v (kLess 0 _) + Sum v.

Lemma aaa {n}(k:nat)(v:t nat (S n)): nth_order (Sumation n v) (kLess k n) =
 (nth_order v (kLess k n)) + (Sum v).
Proof.
move: n k v.
suff main : (forall (n m k : nat) (v : t nat (S m)) (h1 : m - k < S m)
            (h2 : n - k < S n),
  k <= n <= m-> 
  nth_order (Sumation n v) h2 = nth_order v h1
   + Sum v).
  move=> n k v.
  have [klen | ngtk] := (Compare_dec.le_lt_dec k n).
    rewrite (main n n k v); intuition.
    by congr (nth _ _ + _); apply: Fin.of_nat_ext.
  rewrite /nth_order /=.
  rewrite (_ : Fin.of_nat_lt (kLess k n) = Fin.F1).
    by move: (kLess k n); rewrite [n - k](_ : _ = 0) //; lia.
  case: n v {ngtk} => //=.
  move=> n v; rewrite /nth_order (_ : Fin.of_nat_lt _ = Fin.F1) //.
  by move: (kLess (S n) (S n)); rewrite /= (Nat.sub_diag n).
elim => [ | n Ih] m k v h1 h2 [kle nle].
  rewrite /= /nth_order /=.
  congr (nth _ _ + _).
  have k0 : k = 0 by lia.
  move: (kLess 0 m) h1; rewrite k0 Nat.sub_0_r.
  by apply: Fin.of_nat_ext.
rewrite /=.
have [nltSm | neqSm] := Compare_dec.le_lt_eq_dec _ _ kle.
  rewrite /nth_order.
  have [k' k'P] : exists k', S n - k = S k'.
    exists (n - k); lia.
  have h' : S k' < S (S n).
    by lia.    
  have -> /= : Fin.of_nat_lt h2 = Fin.of_nat_lt h'.
    move: h'; rewrite -k'P => h'.
    by apply Fin.of_nat_ext.
  move: (Lt.lt_S_n k' _ _) => {h'}h2.
  have k'P2 : n - k = k' by lia.
  rewrite -[LHS]/(nth_order (Sumation n v) h2).
  move: h2; rewrite -k'P2=> h2.
  rewrite Ih; first by lia.
  by [].
rewrite /nth_order.
have -> /= : Fin.of_nat_lt h2 =
       Fin.of_nat_lt (Nat.lt_0_succ (S n)).
  move: h2; rewrite neqSm Nat.sub_diag; apply: Fin.of_nat_ext.
  lia.
congr (nth _ _ + _).
by move: h1; rewrite neqSm; apply: Fin.of_nat_ext.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found `Vnth_map` in `CoLoR.Util.Vector.VecUtil`.

We can prove `aaa` easily if we rewrite `Sumation` and add `sumMap` to script using `Vnth`.

```
Require Import Psatz.
Require Import CoLoR.Util.Vector.VecUtil.

Definition kLess : forall (k P:nat), (P - k) < (S P).
intros. lia.
Defined.

Definition Sum {A}(v:vector nat A) :nat:= Vector.fold_right Nat.add v 0.

Definition partialSum {n} (v:vector nat n)(m:nat):nat:= m + (Sum v).

Definition Sumation {n} (v:vector nat n) := Vmap (partialSum v) v.

Lemma important {n}(k:nat)(v:vector nat (S n)): Vnth (Sumation v) (kLess k n) = (partialSum v) (Vnth v (kLess k n)).
Proof.
apply Vnth_map.
Qed.
```

Comment: n its current form, this is incomplete, I suggest you respect the names in the question. What you called Sumation in this answer should have another name, say sf you should try to include a proof that Sumation (from the original question) is the same as sumMap and `nth_order` is the same as `Vnth`.